# how to install wx on ubuntu 16.04 for python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

how to install wx latest version on Ubuntu 16.04 for python 3.5?

The error I get:

```
 ~$ sudo apt-get install python3-wxgtk3.0
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done
>   Package python3-wxgtk3.0 is not available, but is referred to by
>   another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'python3-wxgtk3.0' has no installation candidate

Comment: found the way:-  $ sudo pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 wxPython